# Publish test reports rails with xml and html format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, test-coverage

I need to get rails test published report in XML and HTML since Azure DevOps only accepts this two format. I tried [simplecov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) but it generates .json and HTML format. I also tried [simplecov-cobertura](https://github.com/dashingrocket/simplecov-cobertura) but it generates XML only.

I tried the multi-format option for [simplecov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov)

`SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::MultiFormatter.new([SimpleCov::Formatter::HTMLFormatter,
SimpleCov::Formatter::XMLFormatter])`

But it's causing an error `uninitialized constant SimpleCov::Formatter::XMLFormatter`

What are other options or libraries do u suggest to generate reports coverage for rails?

Answer (score 3):

It ends up by using 2 libraries to generate the formats I need so I add to gem file

```
gem 'simplecov-cobertura', require: false
gem 'simplecov', require: false
```

and in rails_helper

```
require 'simplecov'
require 'simplecov-cobertura'
SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::MultiFormatter.new([SimpleCov::Formatter::HTMLFormatter,
SimpleCov::Formatter::CoberturaFormatter])
SimpleCov.start do
    add_filter '/test/'
    add_filter '/config/'
    add_filter '/vendor/'
    add_group 'Controllers', 'app/controllers'
end
```

This way generates both xml and html format